# How to retrieve the raw data from opengl texture mapped in CUDA?

Tags: opengl, cuda, textures, interop

I'm trying to render a scene in OpenGL and map the color and depth texture data to a contiguous CUDA `device_ptr`, similar to `glReadPixels` but on GPU memory. Is it possible?

The data type of color and depth textures are `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, respectively.

I don't have much experience with CUDA, so I only found some examples mapping an OpenGL 2D texture to another CUDA texture, and I would like to just have the reference to the mapped raw data.

I tried to map the `texture2D` with `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` and `cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray`, but since it returns a `cudaArray`, I don't know if I can transform this pointer and use it as a `device_ptr`. Also, it crashes when I try to register the depth texture, which I think it might not be supported, but I would like to try some workaround if there is any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to give an update about what i ended up doing. I ended up just working with the color data, initially discarding depth information.

I used the method **cudaMemcpyFromArrayAsync** to copy the **cudaArray** to a new device vector. It is a deprecated method on CUDA 11.6, but it worked and it was relatively fast since it was a device to device copy
(**cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice**).